On spin structure for Kähler manifolds and square roots of $\det (TX)$
I'm stuck on the proof that for a (compact) Kähler manifold $X$ (of complex dimension $n$), a spin structure on the tangent bundle $TX$ is equivalent to a line bundle $L$ together with an isomorphism $L\otimes L\cong K_X:=\det(T^*X)$.
I'm reading Hitchin's "Harmonic Spinors" where there is a diagram as follows (approx.)
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
U(1) @<<<\widetilde{U(n)} @>>> Spin(2n)\\
@V -^2 V V @VVV @VVV\\
U(1) @<<\det<U(n) @>>> SO(2n)
\end{CD}
where $\widetilde{U(n)}$ is the double cover of $U(n)$ and both diagrams are pullbacks. My understanding is then that a spin structure on $TX$ is equivalent to a map $X\rightarrow B\widetilde{U(n)}$, which is equivalent to a $U(1)$-bundle $L$ such that $L^2\cong \det (TX)$. Finally, a square root of $\det(TX)$ should be equivalent (by taking duals) to a square root of $K_X=\det (T^*X)$ of the canonical bundle.
Is this correct? I'm unsure if the argument does go through square roots of $\det(TX)$.
